# How do I overwrite Camel Body?

Tags: apache-camel

I have used other integration frameworks and libraries before, and in general the way they deal with the message body or payload is to drop everything except the most recent "update" so to speak. Here is an example of what I mean:

XML Message from Queue (payload is XML message) -> use XPath to get something out of XML (payload still XML message) -> Call to some REST API (payload still XML message) -> Return from REST API (payload is now whatever the REST API returned)

I am looking for this sort of behavior in Camel. Right now what Camel is doing is after the "Return from REST API", the payload is whatever the REST API returned **appended with the original XML message**.

What is the best way for me to only refer to the payload/body that the REST API returns?

Comment: could you share an example? Camel does not "append", every processor can change the `in` message and set the "current" value of it (overwriting anything that was there before)

Comment: It is very hard to comment without seeing how your route is built. In general your exchange is overwritten after each call so what you see should not have happen. But need to see your route to give you a better answer.

Comment: This behaviour doesn't sound right. Can you post your route ?

After a simple REST call to a external API, the REST API response will/should overwrite the actual camel body.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange body {exchange.getIn().getBody()} will only contain the response of REST API. Please check the API how it is forming response, it may be appending input xml to output.